# How can I set all the items width are the same in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'd like to set all the items' width the same. because the view has line around it and some text are long and the others are short. So, the items look like stair case or something but I want them to look clean. (Maybe, I need to set the heights the same as well in the future.)

I want to set all the width & height with the longest text among the items.

I have set these three values,

```
var maxLength = 0
var maxWidth = 0
var longestP = 0
```

And, init the values whenever it sets new data.

```
    fun setData(data: ArrayList<AnswerData>?, min: Int?, max: Int?) {
        if (data == null) {
            items = ArrayList()
        } else {
            data.forEach {
                it.isChecked = false
            }
            this.items = data
        }

        this.min = min ?: -1
        this.max = max ?: 30
        maxLength = 0
        maxWidth = 0
        longestP = 0

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

This is the logic that I thought it would work. (But didn't)

```
for( i in 0 until items.size){
    val length = items[i].label!!.length
    if( length > maxLength){
        maxLength = length
        longestP = i
    }
}

if(longestP == position){
    maxWidth = holder.cb!!.measuredWidth
}else{
    resizeView(holder.cb!!, maxWidth, holder.cb!!.measuredHeight)
    notifyItemChanged(position)
}
```

It's resizeView().

```
    private fun resizeView(view: View, newWidth: Int, newHeight: Int) {
        Log.d("size", "$newWidth, $newHeight")
        val params = view.layoutParams
        params.width = newWidth
        params.height = newHeight
        view.layoutParams = params
    }
```

What's the problem?

Comment: if you want to set fixed size, why don't you set Height and Width in xml file?

Comment: I want to fit the width and height with the longest text. and the the longest text is different each time.(Can't expect.) @ST

Comment: yes. if long text can be cut,  you can set maxLine, or maxWidth for make it fit.

Comment: If the text cannot be cut, you can set fixed width, and have the text automatically scroll to reveal the full text contents(Refer here: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2016/08/auto-scrolling-horizontal-running.html). Otherwise, you can set fixed width, and allow the text to extend to 2-3 lines.

Comment: No, it's different from what I want to implement. I want to set all the item views to the longest item among them. the items are different from each API call. It can be 113dp or 52dp or I don't know. The width should be flexible and at the same time, all the items must have the same width. @ST

Comment: @LCZ I don't need scrolling. And all the items isn't and won't be cut. It's wrapping and make one more line if it's long. And that's fine. And that's what I need.

Comment: how about resizeView code in your adapter on Bind? after settext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some part in Adapter, and it works.

```
    var maxLength = 0
    var maxWidth = 0
    var maxHeight = 0
    var longestP = 0
```

```
    fun setData(data: ArrayList<AnswerData>?) {
        ...

        maxLength = 0
        maxWidth = 0
        maxHeight = 0
        longestP = 0

        ...
    }
```

```
    for( i in 0 until items.size){
        val length = items[i].label!!.length
        if( length > maxLength){
            maxLength = length
            longestP = i
        }
    }

    if(longestP == position){
        maxWidth = holder.tv!!.width
        maxHeight = holder.tv!!.height
        items[position].width = maxWidth
        items[position].height = maxHeight
    }else if(holder.tv!!.width < maxWidth){
        items[position].width = maxWidth
        items[position].height = maxHeight
        resizeView(holder.tv!!, items[position].width, items[position].height)
    }
```

The trick is the data model has width and height values. And set the item view's width or height when they are higher than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of your individual views to be `match_parent`, and the width of the `RecyclerView` to be `wrap_content`. This way, all the views will have same width, and not fixed width, dependent on the longest view. If the text is too long, `TextView` will automatically wrap the text to the next line.

My code:

For recycler view

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/single_item" />
```

For single item(I am using CardView)

```xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I wouldn't work. when the parent view wraps the child view and the child view want to match parent...

Comment: I have tried it. Can you post your XML code? Thanks.

Comment: The parent view is `RecyclerView`, the child view is your custom layout for an item (e.g. `single_item.xml`)

Comment: Can you share the code in the answer? If parents wraps the child and the child match_parent, then it will be equivalent to only child wrapping the child. wrapping will work when the items have fixed values, such as XXdp or wrap_content.